# Remembering user's form input without logging in

Tags: javascript, meteor, local-storage, amplifyjs

I've created a simple site where visitors can vote on a particular subject. It consists of a single question and three choices:

```
<template name="addVote">
    <div class="form-row choices">
        <label><input type="radio" name="vote" value="Yes"><i></i><span>Yes</span></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="vote" value="No"><i></i><span>No</span></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="vote" value="Undecided"><i></i><span>I’m Undecided</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <button class="button-submit">Submit and view results</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm using the [Session Amplify](https://github.com/cramrov/meteor-session-amplify) package to store form values in localStorage as well as the DB, which is working perfectly.

```
var vote = $('[name="vote"]:checked').val();
Meteor.call("addVote", vote, function(error, voteId) {
    SessionAmplify.set('vote', vote);
});
```

After the visitor has logged their vote they're shown the global results of the vote as a bar cart. They can only see the results after they vote, though.

What I need to do is remember the user's vote when they visit the site again so they can bypass the vote and go straight to the results, all without forcing them to create an account or log in. I'm already storing their response in localStorage that are accessible by simply running `SessionAmplify.get('vote')`.

How can I use these stored values to pre-populate the form and show them the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    if (localStorage.vote) {
        //user has already cast a vote, reflect this
        document.querySelector(".form-row").querySelector("input[value='"+localStorage.vote+"']").setAttribute("checked", true);
        //disable the submit
        document.querySelector(".button-submit").setAttribute("disabled", true);
    } 

    function setLocalStorageVote()
    {
         //call when user has cast the vote.
         localStorage.vote = document.querySelector(".form-row").querySelector("input[type='radio']:checked").value;
    }


 document.querySelector(".button-submit").onclick = setLocalStorageVote; //using onclick here just for demonstrating purposes. Use addEventListener in production code!
```

```html
<template name="addVote">
    <div class="form-row choices">
        <label><input type="radio" name="vote" value="Yes"><i></i><span>Yes</span></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="vote" value="No"><i></i><span>No</span></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="vote" value="Undecided"><i></i><span>I’m Undecided</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <button class="button-submit">Submit and view results</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Should do it. Just store a *Boolean* and bypass the code to get to the results based on the value of localStorage.vote. `localStorage` is set indefinitely on the client where the vote was cast. Please note that I've removed the Meteor code since I cannot use this in a *fiddle*. This is just to demonstrate that localStorage works.

http://jsfiddle.net/8fzur0h9/1/

Comment: This will set the values in the form when the page loads?

Comment: Why set the value in the form. Wouldn't that submit just another vote? When a user voted bypass the form and show results. Back in the days this was done by storing ones ip-address in the database.

Comment: It has to do with the layout of the page. The left side is the voting form, the right the results. When a user comes back and has already voted I want the form to reflect their answer, and for the results to automatically appear.

Comment: @Mouser - what is the point of this: localStorage.vote = localStorage.vote;

Comment: @RaymondCamden Nothing, left over code. Going to delete it. Thanks for noticing.